# Create a single comma separated list to echo from mysqli results

Tags: php, arrays

```
$get_top10 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name, daily_points, daily_win FROM players WHERE daily_points > 0 ORDER BY daily_points DESC LIMIT 10");
```

I am needing a string like:
name, daily_points, daily_win, name, daily_points, daily_win (etc up to 10 records)

php 7.4.27
mysql 5.6.51-cll-lve

This did the trick, let me know if there is a better or preferred method.

```
$sql = ("SELECT name, daily_points, daily_win FROM players WHERE daily_points > 0 ORDER BY daily_points DESC LIMIT 10");
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "{$row['name']},{$row['daily_points']},{$row['daily_win']},";
            }
        }
```

Comment: With $row being *array*, your question is not about database select but about arrays

Answer (score -1):

you can try this code it will concatenate your php variable to html ','
and it's a preferred method

```
  $sql = ("SELECT name, daily_points, daily_win FROM players WHERE daily_points > 0 ORDER BY daily_points DESC LIMIT 10");
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                     echo $row['name'].','.$row['daily_points'].','.$row['daily_win'];
                }
            }
```

Comment: Nowhere it's a preferred method.

Comment: it's a preferred method.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's just a superstition. One can use anything they prefer, all methods to concatenate variables into a string are equally acceptable.

Comment: yes, you are right we can do both code for the same task but according to me both method are fine and in case i will find any other method for the same i will definitely post here